# creating transport client for elastic search throws unknown host exception

Tags: java, elasticsearch

```
Client client = TransportClient.builder().build()
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("mon1"),9300));
```

I am using the above code snippet to create a transport client for my elastic search using java API, but it throws exception for the method `InetAddress.getByName()`. Says `Unknown Host Exception`. Do I need to create some configuration file for it? If yes, please provide details.

Note :- **I am not using a elastic search cluster on my local machine.**

Comment: What does `mon1` resolve to? Does it work if you use the public IP address of your server instead?

Comment: mon1 is my host name in the ES cluster. No even if i give the IP address of the corresponding host, Its throwing the same exception.

Comment: I am using spring batch to do this, do i need to add some configuration to  my project for elastic search?

Comment: Is it a [public or a private IP address](https://www.iplocation.net/public-vs-private-ip-address)? And what ES version are you using?

Comment: version of the ES is 1.5.2 and the ip address is a private IP address

Comment: Then you need to find out the public IP address (or host name) of your remote cluster, otherwise there's no way you can access your remote cluster from your local machine without it. Networking 101...

Comment: My local machine is in the same network as that of the cluster. the corp network

Comment: What i had asked for is if there is a need for a configuration file? because i saw few codes, they are using configuration files for elastic search and using those values . Is the configuration linking important or i can directly give the ip address or hostname of my cluster in the transport client?

Comment: Actually, in your ES configuration file, you probably need this setting: `network.host: <your private IP>`, indeed.

Comment: Okay thank you. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

InetAddress.getByName throws an unhandled exception "host not found"

Put the entire code in try catch block, It will work. :-)

Note:- Elasticsearch.yml file is needed. Put it in your resources folder if you are using java API

Comment: The exception will be caught, but will your `TransportClient` be connected to ES? Not so sure...

Comment: where exactly do i need to put my elasticsearch.yml file in raptor batch? any clue?

Comment: Have you tried my latest comment to your question? You didn't report back on that.

Comment: That is why i asked the above question, I am trying to use network.host:<my private IP> in elasticsearch.yml, but i am not sure as to where to put this config file as i am using a spring batch

Comment: In the `config` folder of your ES installation folder.

Comment: Thank you sir. Its working now. The config file is important

Comment: and in spring batch, it should be in your src/main/resources folder

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out.